# MathML to LaTeX with php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a MathML representation of a math equation and convert it to the LaTeX representation of that math equation with **php**.

help!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In this site we usually deal only with the LaTeX part. Few people here know php, so I think this question would be better at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: as @PhelypeOleinik says this is mostly off topic but if you are putting this in a web page, presumably you are using mathjax to render the latex, so why not just let mathjax render the mathml directly?